# How to output JSON API values to the DOM with fetch

Tags: javascript

I'm using fetch to pull a JSON file from an api and trying to output the title and url value to the document. However, I am not sure why the document shows [object Promise] in the browser instead of looping through and display the JSON values.

HTML

```
<div class="app"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var app = document.querySelector('.app');
var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

var output = fetch(api)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  json.map(x => {
   `
    <div>
      <h1>${x.title}</h1>
      <img src="${x.url}" />
    </div>
   `

  })
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error loading');
  return `<h1>Error Loading</h1>`;
});


//Tried
app.innerHTML = output;

//Also Tried
app.appendChild(output);
```

Comment: Why yes, `fetch` returns a Promise object. You can't just simply return data from inside that Promise.

Comment: `output` is a promise and you have to wait for it before you try to append to the document.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning `var output = fetch(api)` and not returning any value .

So basically, its keeping value returned by `fetch()` which is a promise.

Try this

```
return json.map(x => {
   `
    <div>
      <h1>${x.title}</h1>
      <img src="${x.url}" />
    </div>
   `

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a pretty dangerous way to do it, so try not to do this and set whatever your API returns. But just to give you an example here.

```js
var app = document.querySelector('.app');
var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

fetch(api)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  let els = json.map(x => {
   return `<div>
      <h1>${x.title}</h1>
      <img src="${x.url}" />
    </div>`
  })
  app.innerHTML=els;
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log('error loading');
  return `<h1>Error Loading</h1>`;
});
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```

What you need to do is to push your elements to the `div` from within `fetch`'s Promise chain

Read more about Promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

Add another then to your promise chain, and assign there.

```js
fetch(api)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    return json.map(x => {
      `
    <div>
      <h1>${x.title}</h1>
      <img src="${x.url}" />
    </div>
   `

    })

  })
  .then(output => {
    //Tried
    app.innerHTML = output;
    //Also Tried
    app.appendChild(output);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log('error loading');
    return `<h1>Error Loading</h1>`;
  });
```

Comment: This also works, but I feel it's still kinda dangerous to insert whatever the API returns.

Comment: The question is clearly how to get the value, not the proper ways to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScripts's `fetch()` meyhod retruns a `Promise` object, and if you don't use `await`, this promise will still promise after `then()`s. So, you should rewrite your code as follows:

```js
var app = document.querySelector('.app');
var api = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos';

fetch(api)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    app.innerHTML = json.map(x => // With { and } you should use return
     `<div>
        <h1>${x.title}</h1>
        <img src="${x.url}" />
      </div>`
    ).join('');
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error loading');
    app.innerHTML = `<h1>Error Loading</h1>`;
  });
```

```html
<div class="app"></div>
```